# Error Converting circular structure to JSON when using vue data

Tags: json, webpack, vue.js

Hello I have an issue with my return dada `bus:bus`. 
I am getting the following error Error Converting circular structure to JSON

Here is my code

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var bus = new Vue();
indexMixin = {
    data: function () {
        return {
            index_data: {
                message : message,
                bus : bus
            }
        }
    },
    ready: function () {

    },


    watch:{

    },
    methods:{

    }
}
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Works for me, where are you converting to JSON? Any `{{bus}}` in your HTML?

Comment: @gurghet i'm only using it to emit event and listen on the parent

Comment: Please write a jsfiddle because the code you posted is working.